# Getting rid of comments below input lines

Tags: front-end

I recently went from an older Mathematica version to 12.1

Everything is fine, but I am struggling with turning off the feature of "explanatory comments" below some input commands/functions etc. as shown in the figure.

I can't find where to turn these off. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the "Show code captions" option under Preferences:

[image]